# Regression line goes out of box?

Tags: r, graphics

```
plot(pressure$temperature,pressure$pressure, 
     main = "Vapor Pressure of Mercury as a Function of Temperature", 
     ylim = c(0, 850), pch = 10)
regline <- lm(pressure$pressure ~ pressure$temperature)
cor(pressure$temperature, pressure$pressure)^2
abline(regline, col = "red")
```

My regression line goes out of the box and off the screen. How can I fix this?

Comment: Mine stays inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

With 99% probability you set `par(xpd=NA)` at some point in your R session.   From `?par`:

> ‘xpd’ A logical value or ‘NA’.  If ‘FALSE’, all plotting is
>             clipped to the plot region, if ‘TRUE’, all plotting is
>             clipped to the figure region, and if ‘NA’, all plotting is
>             clipped to the device region.  See also ‘clip’.

You can (1) use `par("xpd")` to see if that is the case; either (2a) start a clean session where you don't do that; or (2b) set `par(xpd=FALSE)` to reset the default.